# insert custom autocomplete into modal bootstrap react table

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap-table

im using a module for autocompleting suggestions so a user can select some people from the database to be added to a table, it is working great on the top of a custom react table for react, the thing is that i need that autocomplete field to be on a modal but i have not been able to add it to the modal, mainly because i dont know if that modal is atomatically created since it renders forms for every field of the table, but i only need that one autocomplete field.

the autocomplete module is http://react-autosuggest.js.org/ and the git repo https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest#installation, the react table module: react-bootstrap-table at the repo http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/

i was wondering if i have to create a new instance of the table and modify the modal there or by calling a method i can insert that one field i need.

i know this is not such a deep question, just a matter of "the right way to do it"

thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found was creating a custom modal and handling every action from the component that called that modal, so, at the end the insert button called a whole new component that is the modal which had everything needed there.